# Need to change background on GUI using IntelliJ but background is hiding the buttons

Tags: java, image, swing, background, jframe

```
package imgscoring;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import static java.lang.System.exit;

public class IMGSCORING
{

    private JButton button1;
    private JPanel main;
    private JButton button2;
    private JLabel lblLed;
    private JButton button3;
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel logo;
    private static Image i;

    public IMGSCORING() {
        button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                try {
                    runProgam();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                exit(1);
            }
        });

        Image i = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("C:\\Users\\djuwo\\Desktop\\icon.jpg");



    }

    public static void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);
    }

    public void runProgam() throws IOException, InterruptedException  {
        QrScanner run = new QrScanner();
        run.runProgram();
    }

    public JPanel getMain() {
        return main;
    }

    public void setMain(JPanel main) {
        this.main = main;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" IMG FORMING Label Generator");
        frame.setContentPane(new IMGSCORING().main);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\djuwo\\Desktop\\icon.jpg");
        frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());

    }

    private void createUIComponents() {
        // TODO: place custom component creation code here
        logo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("icon.jpg"));
    }
}
```

I am very new to using the gui for Java and based on looking around and seeing others code I can definitely tell mine is way off from how it should look.. Would appreciate feedback on how to properly format my code as well as how to add a background. The program works and buttons respond, icon are changed, etc. But I am unable to change the background. At first I tried the following but that obviously didn't work.

```
frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\djuwo\\Desktop\\icon.jpg")))));
```

Comment: *"I am very new to using the gui.."* Then you should be learning proficiency in the GUI toolkit rather than futzing with background images. As an aside, nothing in that code seems to call the `paint(..)` method.

Comment: Ask your question before showing code + minimize it

Answer (score 0):

In the following solutions, you can see the following steps:

1. Override `paintComponent` of `JPanel`, in order to draw the image in its background.
2. Add any elements you want in the subclassed `JPanel`.
3. Add the subclassed `JPanel` to the content pane of the `JFrame`.
4. `setOpaque(false)` in the subclassed `JPanel` in order to show the background (where we paint the image).

In the first solution, I just paint the image once and not care about filling the frame when it is resized:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class RegularMain extends JPanel {
    private final BufferedImage bimg;

    public RegularMain(final BufferedImage bimg) {
        //super(); //FlowLayout already.
        this.bimg = Objects.requireNonNull(bimg);

        //Add your components here:
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
            super.add(prepare(new JButton("Button " + i)));

        //Allow pixels to show through (ie the backgroung image to be shown):
        super.setOpaque(false);

        //Preparing the preferred size:
        final Dimension prefsz = super.getPreferredSize(); //Gets the preferred size, after adding the components to this panel.
        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Math.max(prefsz.width, bimg.getWidth()), Math.max(prefsz.height, bimg.getHeight())));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(bimg, 0, 0, this);
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    public static JButton prepare(final JButton button) {
        button.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, "You clicked \"" + button.getText() + "\"!"));
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new RegularMain(ImageIO.read(new File("your_image.png"))));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But, another approach is to resize the image to correspond to the panel's size:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TransformMain extends JPanel {
    private final BufferedImage bimg;

    public TransformMain(final BufferedImage bimg) {
        //super(); //FlowLayout already.
        this.bimg = Objects.requireNonNull(bimg);

        //Add your components here:
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
            super.add(prepare(new JButton("Button " + i)));

        //Allow pixels to show through (ie the backgroung image to be shown):
        super.setOpaque(false);

        //Preparing the preferred size:
        final Dimension prefsz = super.getPreferredSize(); //Gets the preferred size, after adding the components to this panel.
        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Math.max(prefsz.width, bimg.getWidth()), Math.max(prefsz.height, bimg.getHeight())));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.scale(getWidth() / (double) bimg.getWidth(), getHeight() / (double) bimg.getHeight());
        g2d.drawImage(bimg, 0, 0, this);
        g2d.dispose();
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    public static JButton prepare(final JButton button) {
        button.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, "You clicked \"" + button.getText() + "\"!"));
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TransformMain(ImageIO.read(new File("your_image.png"))));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And finally another approach is to make the image a `TexturePaint`, if you want the image to be repeated:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.TexturePaint;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TextureMain extends JPanel {
    private final TexturePaint paint;

    public TextureMain(final BufferedImage bimg) {
        //super(); //FlowLayout already.
        paint = new TexturePaint(bimg, new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, bimg.getWidth(), bimg.getHeight()));

        //Add your components here:
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; ++i)
            super.add(prepare(new JButton("Button " + i)));

        //Allow pixels to show through (ie the backgroung image to be shown):
        super.setOpaque(false);

        //Preparing the preferred size:
        final Dimension prefsz = super.getPreferredSize(); //Gets the preferred size, after adding the components to this panel.
        super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(Math.max(prefsz.width, bimg.getWidth()), Math.max(prefsz.height, bimg.getHeight())));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setPaint(paint);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.dispose();
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }

    public static JButton prepare(final JButton button) {
        button.addActionListener(e -> JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(button, "You clicked \"" + button.getText() + "\"!"));
        return button;
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main frame");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new TextureMain(ImageIO.read(new File("your_image.png"))));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The difference in the solutions above is visible when the frame/panel is resized. In the first case, the frame is not supposed to be resized so we only draw the image once, without changing it in size. In the second case the image size follows the panel's size. And in the final case we repeat the image vertically and horizontally up to the panel's size (by using `TexturePaint`).

All the cases have in common that we paint the image in `paintComponent` before everything else and that we `setOpaque` to `false`.